# Setting a mysql table in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I'm using this code to store tables in a variable:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user  = "x";
$password =  "x";

try {
    $account = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=account", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('connection cant be made');
}

try {
    $player = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=player", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('connection cant be made');
}
```

and everything I do I get "connection can't be made". So I found another code and I switched to it and everything works.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";                    // Ip-ul de la server 
$user= "xx";                            // User-ul de conectare la database
$password = "xx";                       // Parola de conectare la database
mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('account');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

?>
but now I have no db assigned to $account and $player and I can't use my site properly. Ideas?

Comment: `die('connection can't be made')` is a parse error

Comment: yeah I edited it when I posted it because it was in my own language. Do you know the solution to my problem?

Comment: for starters, either do and escaping the quote `die('connection can\'t be made')` or `die("connection can't be made")` in double quotes.

Comment: I fixed that. Now can you help me with the main problem?

Comment: Try pdo's error handling https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Will do. I still wait for someone with another alternative.

Comment: 1) mysql_* is deprecated (too old), don't use it. 2) Take a look at this PDO example code: https://gist.github.com/odan/0c3f80eec13ac493ed64fadd0bb1a66e#open-a-database-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$e` you have reason why you can't connect to database. Catch exception and do nothing with it...

```
<?php
define('__DEBUG', true);


try {
    $account = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=account", $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    if(__DEBUG) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
    die('connection cant be made');
}
```

for use 2 connections in (not so^) old way style:

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect();
$con2 = mysqli_connect();
mysqli_query('query', $con1);
mysqli_query('query', $con2);
```

^ use `mysqli_` instead `mysql_`